# How to send macOS logs to syslog (graylog) server from /etc/asl.conf

Tags: macos, logs

I have recently setup a cool [Graylog](https://www.graylog.org/) server for myself which I have various machines now sending their log output to. It's great and is helping me a ton. I want to do the same with macOS. There are outdated instructions on how to do this with syslog on macOS, but I think they don't work because macOS is pivoting to Apple System Log over syslog.

I suspect the necessary entry required to make asl send logs as I desire should be straight-forward. However I've not yet found a working solution.

Any specific suggestions would be great. I'll post back when I find a solution myself.

**-- Update 1 --**
I've found that the graylog notes on logging via a line added in /etc/syslog.conf do in fact work, but send the logs via UDP. I tried using both the "@" and "@@" tokens ahead of the destination which I've seen used to distinguish which network protocol is used. I suppose macOS's syslog implementation favours UDP. I'd still like to know how to do this via /etc/asl.conf, so the question stands.

Comment: Have you find out any solutions on this?

Comment: No. I’ve only put a couple hours in to this. At least the syslog approach actually works, but it does seem like the “wrong” answer.